# Transaction rollback in DAO method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

From my DAO method I need to return a result (even if exception occured). I try to do it in such a manner by it doesn't work in case of exception(I have an exception: `don't flush the Session after an exception occurs`).

```
@Repository
@Transactional(rollbackFor=HibernateException.class)
public class UserDAO {

    @Override
    public boolean save(Proxy proxy) {
        try{
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(proxy);
        }
        catch(HibernateException e){
            //TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

However when I uncomment `//TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();`
all works like I expect. I know that documentation don't recommend to use this approach, but annotation rollback doesn't work for me. Can you explain, please, why? Can I modify the code to get it work, if it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring will rollback only if the exception is thrown by the method. If it's thrown and caught inside the method, Spring doesn't know anything about the exception, and thus considers that everything went fine, and thus doesn't rollback the transaction.

So, either keep the call to setRollbackOnly, or, much preferred, don't use boolean results to indicate that an operation succeeded or failed. An exception **should** be thrown if the save wasn't successful.

Answer (score 4):

`rollbackFor` attribute works if annotated method throws specified exception. In your case exception is catched inside the method and is not propagated up so `rollbackFor` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you do need to return a value instead of throwing an exception to your caller, you do need to rely on setRollbackOnly(), which I don't think is bad, but pretty standard way.

Besides, I think throwing an exception is a better idea because your caller has no notion of what goes wrong when there is a 'false'. Otherwise, you might need to return an error code or error message or something more meaningful than a 'false'.